# How to create this matrix in matlab efficiently? Without for loop?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to create a N*N matrix A by this function:

[image]

where x and y are N-d vectors. I can just create is by 4 nested for loop, but how to achieve it more efficiently? Are there any methods without for loop?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume it is `cos(k*y_j)` and not `n`?

Comment: what are `M` and `K`?

Comment: If you know what M and K are, you can do everything in matrix form which saves you from loop.

Answer (score 0):

using element-wise .* operations will be dramatically faster than 4 nested for loops.  I think you want something like this:

```
M = 100;
K = 100;
N = 40;
x = linspace(0,1,N);
y = linspace(0,1,N);

%order reversed matches i,j notation in question
[Y,X] = meshgrid(y,x);
A = zeros(size(X));

for m = 1:M
    for k = 1:K

        A = A + sqrt(m^2 + k^2)*sin(m*X).*cos(k*Y);

    end 
end
```